# ¿Como eliminar un registro mediante un input en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Necesito eliminar un registro de la base de datos mediante un input. Yo ingreso un codigo en el input y al apretar el boton deberia borrase un registro que tenga el codigo ingresado en el input.

**En la vista**

```
<form action="{{ route('otps.destroy', 'codigo') }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                    <input type="text" name="codigo">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" type="submit">Entregar</button>

                </form>
```

**En el controlador**

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->codigo;
        $otp = Otp::find($id);
        $otp->delete();
    }
```

**Rutas**

```
Route::resource('otps', 'OtpController');
```

Comment: Este código que muestras que error te da?

Comment: El valor que pasas en la ruta llamado codigo que tiene?